# ci skip not working with bitbucket

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, webhooks

I'm currently working on a CI setup with Jenkins and bitbucket.

I've configured a webhook in bitbucket to trigger my builds on a push to the repo.

Now I'm currently trying to skip certain builds to prevent an endless loop.
I'm familiar with gitlab and I know they have an option to enable `[ci-skip]` to prevent web hooks from being triggered when this is anywhere in the commit message.

I've tried `[ci-skip]` and `[ci skip]` for bitbucket as well but it doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know how you can achieve this by using bitbucket?
I know there are plugins for Jenkins but they will trigger the build and then just cancel it. But it will remain in the history so I prefer to not use this solution.

Hope someone has tried this before and knows the solution.

Comment: this is a terrific idea. are you using bitbucket cloud or bitbucket server? in case someone has done this, i'm pretty sure the answer will depend on which product.

Comment: @burnettk My company is using the cloud server unfortunately. I believe there is a Jenkins plugin for the server version that will help you do something similar.